# Regular expression of 2 tags open and close and many lines

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match this block here

```
/code\

int foo(string $bar, int $bleh); Simple function!

bool is_even(mixed $var); Checks if a variable is even.

\code/
```

my pattern is `"/code\\(.*?)\code/"`

yet no matches found!

Okay it's very hard to show what I mean in stackoverflow due to all the restrictions on html.

But code tags are basically HTML tags with opener and closer tag.

does regex not handle multiple lines? yes I do have multi-line flag triggered

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most regex implementations, `multi-line` mode with the `m` modifier does not let the `.` match line breaks, but causes the `^` to match the start of a line and the `$` match the end of a line.

What you need is to enable `dot-all` mode by adding the `s` modifier. And if your language's regex implementation does not support that modifier (JavaScript does't, if memory serves me right), you can mimic this using `[\s\S]` instead of `.` (DOT).

Be aware that you will get in trouble matching stuff like:

nested tags:

```
/code\

/code\

...

\code/

\code/
```

(matched text: `/code\ /code\ ... \code/`)

or commented tags:

```
/code\

...

<!-- \code/ -->

\code/
```

(matched text: `/code\ ... <!-- \code/`)

Comment: Alright thanks alot bart i'll check it out tommorrow going to bed for now. so it should look like (*[\s\S]?), I'm using Regular Expressions 5.5 from VBScript engine, yeah I don't believe I have dot-all option.

Comment: @SSpoke, no, not `(*[\s\S]?)` but `([\s\S]*?)`. You're welcome, of course.

Comment: @SSpoke, are you also unable to embed those flags as `(?s)` and `(?m)`?

Comment: Yup ([\s\S]*?) works beautifully! just another little trick i'd have to add to my gmail drafts haha my little codebank

Comment: @tchrist: VBScript implements ECMA-262, so no embedded mode modifiers, and no single-line/dot-all mode at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "global" option to tell the re engine to treat the whole string as one line.

Comment: Without the global option, at least one match should have been reported. But no match is found, so adding that will make no difference I think.

Comment: I already have that option enabled Mohamed, Set bbcodeRegex = New RegExp
bbcodeRegex.IgnoreCase = True
bbcodeRegex.Global = True
bbcodeRegex.MultiLine = True

Comment: You have `Global=True` and `MultiLine=True` try setting `MultiLine=False` and see if that works?

Answer (score 0):

You need to double up one of your backslashes:

```
/code\\(.*?)\\code/
            ^--- right here
```

Comment: yeah if you use symbols which are used by regex but I was focusing on html tags <,> but this will help ppl out

Comment: I'm just saying that your pattern, which you specified in your question, wasn't going to work. If you're actually using a different pattern, fine, but you should post your actual use case in your questions in the future.